# Partially used on the application

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

Is it possible to use Angular not for all the application but only for some parts ?

I use Express for the server side and few pages are already made. Should I rebuild them or can I use Angular for only some parts ?

Comment: If you build already build pages in angular it will be good for future modifications, but if you want you can use angular in only some part of application.

Comment: I've already built pages without Angular. How can I continue if I include for only some pages Angular ? What will the structure look like ? Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to build only some page in angular, do it something like this:

Add angular script in header.

define your body like this:

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
</body>
```

Define module like this:

```
<script>
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
</script>
```

Now on those pages where you want to use angular define a ng-controller at the very first div like this:

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
</div>
```

and now define your controller like this:

```
<script>
 app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {          
     //here you can define all your logic for page.
 });
</script>
```